# Prove that dot product of two vectors x and y equals to zero, for all $\vec{y} \in {\mathbb{R^{n}}}$ if and only if vector x equals to zero

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, vectors

Suppose that $\vec{x} \in {\mathbb{R^{n}}}$ . Show that $\vec{x}\cdot\vec{y} = 0$ for all $\vec{y} \in {\mathbb{R^{n}}}$ if and only if $\vec{x} = 0.$

To prove it, I'm first proving, that if $\vec{x} = 0$, then $\vec{x}\cdot\vec{y} = 0$ for all $\vec{y} \in {\mathbb{R^{n}}}$.

To prove the other way round:
If $\vec{x}\cdot\vec{y} = 0$, then $$x_1\cdot y_1 + x_2\cdot y_2 + ... + x_n\cdot y_n  = 0$$
It would be zero, when x is zero, y is zero, or vectors are orthogonal.
But how to prove it formally, showing that for **all** possible y, dot product would be equal to zero. Can't wrap my head around in this type of proves.

Comment: Take $y=x$.$\phantom{}$

Comment: @user1551 To be honest i don't understand, how this approach proves what was required. But I'm pretty sure, it's because of my proving skills. Thanks for help anyway, will try it out.

Comment: I suggest proving for $n=1$ first. Then for $n=2$ and find out if the proof generalizes to $n>2$.

Comment: @wintermute   the key word in the second part of the proof is EVERY. You have a vector $x$ which is known to be orthogonal to EVERY vector $y$. Hence $x$ is orthogonal to $x$. Etc.

Comment: That's a super easy question. What's the source? Because this is elementary algebra.

Comment: @Ned Thank you, I've missed an important part, that says, that zero vector, x in this case, is orthogonal to every other vector. Thanks you, ,once again. user1551 meant the same.

Comment: @chemandmath I've never said, that it was a complicated question. It comes from "Introduction to Linear and Matrix Algebra". I'm learning how to write proofs, so what i was lacking - an understanding, how to write proof formally. If the goal was to show, that for EVERY y vector,  i can't prove it by exhausting all possibilities. Didn't know how to generalize. Anyway, thank you all for help.